# Change column type from TEXT to INTEGER to store date object

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to upgrade an Android app that has a SQLite database. In the new version we decided to use INTEGER (the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`) to store `java.util.Date` objects instead of TEXT (ISO8601 strings: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`).

Is it possible to change column type? Or should I add a new column and then convert date objects to long and then delete the old column and at the end rename new column? Or Is there a better/standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you...

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS **TEMP_TABLE** (id integer primary key autoincrement, **col2change integer not null**, ...)

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE SELECT * FROM EXISTING_TABLE

DROP TABLE EXISTING_TABLE

ALTER TABLE TEMP_TABLE RENAME TO EXISTING_TABLE
```

Comment: Is possible to convert types on the fly? `INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE SELECT * FROM EXISTING_TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) and as you have said:

> add a new column and then convert date objects to long and then delete
>   the old column and at the end rename new column

On the other hand you can just put int in column with TEXT affiliation since sqlite doesn't really care about types in **most cases**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as @delor said SQLite is almost typless, see http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html
You can update your table by just one query:
`update t set d = strftime('%s', d)`